# Laravel Virtual host doesnt work

Tags: apache, laravel, laravel-5, xampp, virtualhost

Iam trying to make virtual host for laravel 5.2 in apache server, but everytime i tried to access the virtual host it always shows "This site cant be reached", but i can access it through localhost:folder/public

I already setting the httpd-vhost

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp2/htdocs/"
    ServerName localhost

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp2/htdocs/belajarlaravel/public"
    ServerName belajarlaravel.dev
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp2/htdocs/merchandise3-project/public"
    ServerName merchandise.dev

</VirtualHost>
```

and my host

```
127.0.0.1    localhost
127.0.0.1    belajarlaravel.dev
127.0.0.1    merchandise.dev
```

I can access the localhost but for other host they still showing server not found and site cannot be reached. Can u give me some advice ? Thank You for your attention.

Comment: Check in httpd.conf if you're including httpd-vhost.conf file

Comment: @Nartub already check it and Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf is active, i dont know why my vhost doesnt work because last two days still worked perfectly

Comment: I dont know why but when iam using firefox developer, and chrome my vhost always doesnt work, but when iam switching to edge i can use it normally. Maybe some trouble in browser

Comment: Sounds strange.. something about your hosts file?

Answer (score 3):

maybe the .dev ending is considered unsafe by Chrome, try .com